# Using Versions and SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, versions

I've set up an SVN repo and I've downloaded the free version of Versions. Now, how do I get started with Versions? I get an error when I try to create a repo bookmark.

Comment: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
Unable to open repository 'file://localhost/Users/newcomputer/Desktop/music%20startup'

Answer (score 1):

Using Versions to connect to our SVN server is great. I would say I haven't seen a better SVN client for the Mac, so hopefully this will help:

So here's what I did to set up each of my repos:

- Start Versions, and created a new REPOSITORY (bookmark to a URL)
- You can name it something convenient, I try to use no spaces in my name.
- Location should be the URL to your actual repository http://svnserver.blah/svn/repo-name
- Enter username and password if you need to.
- Then, once it creates the bookmark to a repository, you should highlight it on the left of your Versions window and "check out" a copy of it. Even if it's an empty repo, Versions will ask you what local folder you want to use to store the local copy.
- You can move files to your local folder using the Finder, and then when you look back in versions you'll see your files with "?" icons. Highlight any/all of those you want to add and click the ADD button (upper-right).
- Finally, you can COMMIT any files you highlight (or just click on the folder itself at the top) and you will sync your changes to the server copy. It will ask you for a note/comment if you want to add one.
- Likewise if this is a shared repo, when you start Versions you'll see a highlighted number next to your repository if new files have been added. In that case, press the UPDATE button and the remote files will be synced to your local copy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a new repository on the server? The error you got may indicate that there is not yet a Subversion repository at that location.

Comment: What Subversion server did you install? If it's the standard one, then the `svn init` command is what you're looking for. Otherwise, Versions might have commands to do the same thing, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @Justin Meltzer: It sounds like you're pretty new to Subversion. I recommend having a look through the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) which describes what it means to set up a server and how you would go about doing that.

Answer (score 0):

checkout [svn edge](http://www.open.collab.net/go/csvne2_r2a/). Its more easier to manage. However to use subversion  you need to know version control concepts. Also if you brief about your usage, can give  you more useful links. Of course subversion book is the best place to start with.

Comment: svn edge is Windows and Linux only, the OP is on Mac

Comment: @CharlesB: there is no explicit mentioning of Mac in the question.

Comment: Actually Versions is a Mac software :)